# UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad with "ABC" Button in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

When i set  UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad, it gives first Character Keyboard(ABC..).After pressing 123, it gives number pad in which THe Button ABC is available to go to character keyboard.but when i set UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,it is not giving "ABC" Button.How can I bring first Number Pad with ABC Option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your custom button in `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` type keyboard as [described here.](http://forourson.com/?p=95)

Now, you just need to change keyboard's type in button's click method.

Comment: That url is not giving right output  for iphone 4? any thing to do?